# Заполнение поля адреса с подгрузкой данных из яндекса (как получить район города по адресу)?

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api

Есть поле ввода, при заполнении которого из Яндекса автоматически подгружаются похожие адреса. Данные хранят в себе название страны, области, района, населенного пункта. Но вот не нашел где можно взять район населенного пункта если такой есть в этом городе.

Например: как получить название "Центральный район" если я вписал "Оренбург, советская 21"?

читал что можно обратным геокодированием
получил геокод

```
var Geocoder = ymaps.geocode('Оренбург, ул. Советская 31');
```

как сделать обратное геокодирование не понимаю

возможно я его уже сделал вот такие данные получил на выходе
но здесь нет района города. Возможно он хранится в другом элменте массива или он должен быть точно тут. Из за того что раньше с этим не работал. Не уверен где точно нужно искать. Может быть яндекс просто по Оренбургу не отдает районы. И нужно брать какой то другой сервис.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Обратное геокодирование - получение адреса из координат. То есть вам нужно получить по адресу 'Оренбург, ул. Советская 31' точку на карте, а потом из этой точки снова получить адрес.

Comment: про это у меня последнее предложение в вопросе)) не получается, точнее даже не понял обратное я геокодировнаие делаю или нет. Если до то какие данные обязательны на вход. Вдруг я не все переда. Мне бы короткий пример. ничего лишнего не надо

Comment: Попробуйте указать параметр `"kind": "district"`, в ответе появится район. Вот пример из http-геокодера https://geocode-maps.yandex.ru/1.x/?geocode=55.098464,51.766237&kind=district (Обратное геокодирование = получение адреса из координат, прямое геокодирование = получение координат из адреса)

Comment: Эх непонятно) координаты то сервер отдаёт но рабочую функцию куда можно было бы подставиьь координаты как аргумент, я так и не нашёл. Или не понял( попробую в php api поискать. Все равно данные уходят на сервер.  Так что будет нормально что на сервере и будет подкачиваться район

Comment: @Reni так и решил, при заполнении адреса получаю данные через js, а при сохранении объекта недвижимости обращаусь по http получаю район и сохраняю в базу

Comment: Обратите внимание, что "сохранять в базу" допускается лишь на расширенных коммерческих тарифах - https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/commercial/doc/concepts/jsapi-geocoder.html#jsapi-geocoder__tariff-plus Во всех прочих случаях вы можете лишь оперировать данными для решения текущих (realtime) задач.